# Why did the mailbox at the Lake House allow time travel?

Tags: the-lake-house

A simple enough question, and one that hopefully has a simple answer. In the [Lake House](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0410297/), the magic mailbox at the eponymous Lake House serves as a portal through time, allowing Alex (in the past) to communicate with Kate (in the future) and vice versa.

[image]

**In-universe, what made the mailbox special?**

Comment: @amaranth - I assumed it was nargles.

Comment: @Valorum - everyone knows it's the ground pixie wings that allow time travel, not nargles!

Comment: Voting to leave open. It may well be that there's no SFF behind the workings of the mailbox, and it may well never be explained; however it is a worthwhile question to find out here.

Comment: @Mooz - I'm at a loss why anyone would vote down a question about a time-travel movie.

Comment: @kjw - Ewww. https://m.popkey.co/d85ca8/aj1kk.gif

Comment: @Valorum I'm guessing three reasons.  1) Sandra Bullock.  2) Keanu Reeves.  3) The movie was terrible.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo - I kept waiting for the bit with the bus that couldn't slow down. Wasn't disappointed.

Comment: I'm 99% certain that the answer (if it exists) is either in *Il Mare* origins, or even in some obscure Jane Austen reference. But likely *Il Mare*. Unfortunately, I don't know anyone fluent in Korean so contacting the screenwriters is out of realm of possible.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - Did any of Jane Austen's novels have a time-traveling robot?

Comment: @Valorum - Are you insinuating that I actually *read* any of Jane Austen's novels? :)

Comment: I think the answer is - Movie Stuff and Plot Stuff... :)

Comment: @rincewind - I remain convinced that there's always a plot reason,  even if that reason is "because magic".

Comment: @Valorum That is truly a noble cause!! :)

Answer (score 6):

### We don’t know

Unfortunately, there is little to no information to point to a definitive answer.  The main characters worry about the *possibilities* of the mailbox, but don’t really speculate as to how it works. Note that this is from the original script, so the characters’ names are different:

> LUCY (V.O.) Okay. One thing worries me. What if, in sending these letters, in communicating like this, we accidentally tamper with the course of time itself, altering human history forever in the process?

In *Il Mare*,  or  시월애, the Korean film that *The Lake House* was based on, there is no more indication of why the mailbox allows communication between times.  From the English subtitles, we learn nothing more than that the mailbox was responsible—which, of course, we already knew:

> 00:30:34,265 --> 00:30:37,166
> It was a mail-box. The mail-box!
>
> 00:30:41,239 --> 00:30:43,799
> Yes it was. It was because of the mail-box.

That said, both main characters have a connection to the Lake House in some way, which might be as close to an explanation as we have.

> LUCY (V.O.):  So I did. I drove to the Lake House. And that was the day I got your first letter.
>
> INT. ARCHITECTURE SCHOOL - LATER
>
> After the reception, Henry and a few other STUDENTS help fold chairs, clean up.
>
> CONTINUED; LUCY (V.O.):  **It's a place we both love, and it's a place your father built**, so I hope you can find some solace there.

In particular, since Alex’s father built the Lake House, perhaps he (or his connection to Alex) is responsible in some way for its properties.

Elsewhere in the script, there is a not-so-subtle reference to the relationship between Alex and Kate vis-à-vis the Lake House:

> HENRY My project is informed and inspired by a metaphor of the loop, or fugue -- **interlocking, repeating patterns in time and/or space that generate meaning and structural complexity via their contrapuntal interweaving and mutual interdependence, as much as by paradox and apparent contradiction**. Around the table -- generally approving looks. Henry pulls out a rolled-up poster.

Henry is speaking of creating an architectural project that embodies the temporal complexities of an Escher drawing, which seems a good description of the Lake House (though he did not construct the Lake House, of course). **Of course, this brings us no closer to figuring out *why* the mailbox was a portal.**

---

If we assume, though, that (as in many such romantic films), the mailbox served a purpose with regard to their relationship, it presumably was to prevent Alex from dying so that he and Kate could be together. Alex died before Kate ever had a chance to meet him:

> HENRY: He died. Two years ago.
>
> ON LUCY
>
> Beat.
>
> BACK TO SCENE
>
> HENRY (realizing): Two years ago today, actually, There was an accident...
>
> Lucy tries to take this in.

Without time travel, they would never have had an opportunity to be together. **This might be the *reason* for the mailbox working as it did (though it says nothing about the mechanism).**

Comment: I like this. I didn't recall Alex' father referring to the house itself as being inspired by loops and paradoxes.

Comment: @Valorum - That was not his father, alas. That was Henry, whom I believe was Alex's friend. Still, I think it is meant to be meaningful dialogue.

Comment: Henry was Alex's brother. Clearly he's learned something from his dear old dad the master architect.

Comment: Oops, brother. Silly me!

Comment: She did get to meet him, he died in her arms, it just took most of the film to work that out.

Comment: I've awarded a bounty for the reference to Escher/paradoxes. I'm still sure there's a fully canon answer out there somewhere but I'll have to learn Korean to find it :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is deliberately no science between the temporal link of the mailbox.  At most, there is an emotional link between the two main characters and the lake house itself.  It's one of the things that a lot of people complain about with the movie.
This link complains most scientifically about it.
http://www.thebulletproofpatriot.com/2011/09/the-mailbox-inconsistency-a-scientific-criticism-of-the-lake-house-movie/

In short, there isn't an "in universe" explanation, because in forcing reality to warp enough for the concept to work, it would end up destroying universes. At the most stretchy explanation, its due to two people 'Needing' contact that badly at the same time that a link forms.

Even the most romantic of us turn our nose up at the idea and drag it out into the street to shoot it.

This is the most thorough review of the movie, its background, and the focus of the acting and directing in the movie.  http://www.whoaisnotme.net/articles/2006_xxxx_lak.htm  There really isn't an in world explanation of the effect.

***In response to the comments:***
It's a plot device.  The more romantic would say 'Because Love!'.  In this case, its a plot device that might as well hang a sign on it that says 'I'm a plot device.'  This is complained about often in reviews and comments on the movie.

To revisit:
Why did the mailbox at the Lake House allow time travel?  ***Because the writers wanted it to.***

Comment: You say that there's **deliberately no science**. Do you have anything that backs that up?

Comment: http://www.nytimes.com/2006/06/16/movies/16lake.html?_r=0

Comment: That appears to be a film review by someone who doesn't have any special connection to the makers of either the film or its predecessor.

Comment: http://www.nytimes.com/2006/06/16/movies/16lake.html?_r=0 References the lack of science involved and the lack of an explanation.  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0410297/ - references that 'Heaven breaks time' to heal broken hearts.  Again, a stretch with nothing in the movie to back that up.  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0410297/board/nest/210409215?ref_=tt_bd_2, blames The Doctor and the Tardis, which is again just a reference to Zero in world explanation.https://www.theguardian.com/film/filmblog/2014/apr/01/the-lake-house-guilty-pleasure-keanu-reeves-sandra-bullock - and the ever popular magic.

Comment: The comments system is messing me up.  I reference the reviews because most film critics are also given movie summaries to 'explain' bits that need explaining.  The references by the critics to a LACK of an explanation is an explanation in itself.

Comment: Studios will often send out a summary that gives critics an overview of the general plotting. If you could find **that**, that might give you a good answer.

Comment: With even further review, going back to the original Il Mare, made in Korea, the 'Explanation' comes down to 'Effin' magic'.  meaning there ISN'T an in world reason for it.  It just is.  There is no logical "In World" reason for it.

Comment: An answer that references something from the film that *inspired* The Lake House would be worth mentioning. Reviews aren't especially worthwhile unless you have reason to expect the reviewer has some special insight into the film (for example having interviewed them).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the premise is that the house is a paradox, with different meanings for father, son and Kate... of course, there's no explaining it. There had to be some portal of communication past/future for the story to be possible.

The interesting thing is that the man died in the beginning in the bus accident, so was "dead" the whole time the romantic communication was taking place. By sending the note telling him not to come meet her, Kate would have changed reality that had already happened in her own time. Kinda hard to wrap one's head around that.

Stuff that bother me more than the mailbox includes the tree, which is both of their times. How can it be both a young tree and a full grown tree at the same time?

And the dog footprints... Kate lived there two years earlier, and apologized for the prints she said were already there when she moved in. But he already lived in the house when the dog made the prints. If they are exactly two years apart, she would have been there with him, right?
  Speaking of the dog, Jack is with both of them at exactly the same time, two years apart. Unless there were two dogs, that would be impossible.
  Also, if they are exactly two years apart, it can't be the same day of the week, as they movie says, the calendar doesn't work that way. Also, a Leap Year is not accounted for, so the closest they could be would be two days off from an exact year.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question.